# Tracking down source of ZXing failure to decode particular QR code

Tags: qr-code, zxing

I generated about 1300 .png files for various QR codes using the rqrcode gem, all very similar in terms of content (version 2, ascii encoding, level M data correction). Of those, about 2% couldn't be scanned by the ZXing software either on my local machine or on the website http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx. I tried another online site and got the same results.

The failed QR codes scan fine using the Android app on my phone produced by the ZXing team.  I've tried a variety of different image formats and higher sampling rates, none of which makes a difference. Any guidance on how to debug this would be appreciated.  I've attached one of the failed images below:

[image: z]

Comment: Could you remove the whitespace at the bottom (I think your barcode image is not cropped)?

Comment: I could remove the whitespace, I suppose, but I wanted to provide the entire image that's failing, including the black border added by the prawn-qrcode gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost certainly a false positive finder pattern, which is much easier to find when the image is 'pure' like this. Try the PURE_BARCODE hint for images like this, as it will be much faster and should work on anything. But it's only for non-photos with only a barcode on a white field.

See also https://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=1745

Comment: I'll try that if I can as part of trying to diagnose what's going on, but I have several issues with that including: a) I'm working through a Ruby wrapper gem and I'm not sure I can pass that hint in, b) I would have thought the presence of the thin outside border would make the image "not pure", c) in the "real" application I want to have some regular text on the image as well, which I'm assuming would also be incompatible with it being a "pure image".  I'll also try placing this image in the middle of a busy page as well.

Comment: Oh, that border is part of the image, yeah. That won't work. The issue is that it's far easier to find phantom finder patterns in an image like this. It sounds weird, but try rotating the image 90 / 180 / 270 if the normal path fails and it is likely to work.

Comment: Although I don't have a solution, after finding and reading the discouraging https://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=1745, I'm upvoting and accepting because this clearly seems to be the situation. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try a rotation? it's not 0 lines of code, but it's like 3. That's the usual trick if you can't crop or otherwise can't control the barcode.

Comment: I'm trying that now, but please check out my last two comments on the ZXing discussion group on issue #1745.

Comment: The 90 degree rotations didn't help at all, but a 5 degree rotation of the QR code prior to scanning took care of it. Still looking forward to your thoughts on my ZXing discussion group comments.

Comment: Sorry for not noticing. I was expecting an email notification from the discussion group and didn't get one as far as I can tell. I'll read it now.